Exact value for $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}(\arctan^2{x})dx$
Is it possible for me to evaluate the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}
\arctan^{2}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$
without the aid of a calculator ?.
I know that an elementary form of the integral does not exist by plugging it into an integral calculator, but I was wondering if it is possible for us to evaluate the definite integral using some advanced techniques ?.
Thank you.

Are you asking for the integral of $\tan^{-1}(\tan^{2}(x))$ ?

Just by substitution $x\mapsto \tan\varphi$ and integration by parts, you will get: $$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\arctan^2{x}\ \textrm{d}x=\frac{{\pi}^2\sqrt{3}}{9}-\operatorname{Cl_{2}(\pi/3)}=0.88446...$$
where $\operatorname{Cl_{2}(\pi/3)}$ is the Gieseking's Constant. This is the best you can do.

@Mathematics Then they wouldn't be going up to $\sqrt3$.

With a bit of work you get to
$$\int \arctan^2 x dx = x\arctan^2 x-\frac12 \arctan x \log(1+x^2)+\log2\arctan x + \Im \left{\mbox{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+ix}2\right)\right}+C.$$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\arctan(x)^2\text{dx}$$
$$\overset{x=\tan t}{=}\int_0^{\pi\over3}t^2\sec^2t \mathrm{d} t$$
$$\overset{\text{IBP}}{=}t^2\tan t \Big|_0 ^{\pi\over3} -2\int_0 ^{\pi\over3}t\tan t\mathrm{d} t$$
$$\overset{\text{IBP}}{=}\frac{ \pi^2\sqrt{3}}{9}-2\left(-t\ln(\cos t)\Big|_0^{\pi\over3}+\int_0 ^{\pi\over3}\ln(\cos t)\mathrm{d} t\right)$$
$$= \frac{ \pi^2\sqrt{3}}{9}-\frac{ 2\pi}{3}\ln2 -2 \underbrace{\int_0 ^{\pi\over3}\ln(\cos t)\mathrm{d} t}_{I_1}$$
Using the series expansion of $\ln\cos t$:
$$I_1= \int_0 ^{\pi\over3}-\ln2 -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cos2nt}{n}\mathrm{d} t$$
$$=-\frac{ \pi\ln2}{3}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\sin\frac{2\pi n}{3}}{2n^2}$$
$$=-\frac{ \pi\ln2}{3}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}-n\pi\right)}{2n^2}$$
$$=-\frac{ \pi\ln2}{3}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)}{2n^2}$$
$$I=  \frac{ \pi^2\sqrt{3}}{9}-\frac{ 2\pi}{3}\ln2 -2I_1$$
$$=  \frac{ \pi^2\sqrt{3}}{9}-{\frac{ 2\pi}{3}\ln2 }
+{\frac{ 2\pi}{3}\ln2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin \frac{\pi n}{3}}{n^2}$$
$$\boxed{= \frac{ \pi^2\sqrt{3}}{9}-\mathrm{Cl}_2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}$$
Using the definition that $\mathrm{Cl}_2\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{n^2}$. Another approach would be to use the dilogarithm, but that is going to be pretty tedious and the answer doesn’t look nice.

There's a MathWorld page on $\mathrm{Cl}_2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$ by the way.

Via integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\left(\arctan x\right)^2 d x 
= & {\left[x\left(\tan ^{-1} x\right)\right]_0^{\sqrt{3}}-2 \int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{x \tan ^{-1} x}{1+x^2} d x } \\
= & \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi^2}{9}-\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1} x d\left(\ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right) \\
= & \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi^2}{9}-  \underbrace{ \left[\tan ^{-1} x \ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right]_0^{\sqrt{3}}}_{=\frac{\pi}{3}\ln 4  } +\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
For the last integral, putting $x=\tan \theta$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} d x & =\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \ln \left(\sec ^2 \theta\right) d \theta =-2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \ln (\cos \theta) d \theta
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \ln (\cos \theta) d \theta & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \ln\left(\frac{e^{\theta i}+e^{-\theta i}}{2}\right) d \theta \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \ln \left(e^{\theta i}+e^{-\theta i}\right) d \theta-\frac{\pi}{3} \ln2 \\
& =\int_0^ \frac{\pi}{3} \ln \left(e^{\theta i}\left(1+e^{-2 \theta i}\right) \right)d \theta-\frac{\pi}{3} \ln 2\\
& =\Re\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \ln \left(1+e^{-2 \theta i}\right) d \theta-\frac{\pi}{3} \ln 2 \\
& =\Re\left[-\frac{i}{2}\left[\operatorname{Li_ 2}\left(-e^{-2 \theta i}\right)\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\right]-\frac{\pi}{3} \ln 2 \\
& =\Re\left[-\frac{i}{2}\left[\operatorname{Li_ 2}\left(-e^{-\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}\right)-\operatorname{Li_ 2}(-1)\right]\right]-\frac{\pi}{3} \ln 2 \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \Im\left[\operatorname{Li_ 2}(-e^{-\frac{2 \pi}{3}i})\right]-\frac{\pi}{3} \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting back yields
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\left(\arctan x\right)^2 d x &= \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi^2}{9} -\frac{\pi}{3}\ln 4-2 \times \left[\frac{1}{2}  \Im\left[\operatorname{Li_ 2}(-e^{-\frac{2 \pi}{3}i})\right] -\frac{\pi}{3}\ln2  \right]\\&= \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi^2}{9} -\Im\left[\operatorname{Li_ 2}(-e^{-\frac{2 \pi}{3}i})\right]\\&= \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi^2}{9} -\Im\left[\operatorname{Li_ 2}\left( \frac{1+\sqrt 3 i}{2}  \right)\right]\end{aligned}
 $$
Wish it helps.
